# Can I change the Time Zone of Type ORM for another time zone?

Tags: timezone, nestjs

I'm encountering a problem related to timezone handling in my NestJS application using TypeORM for database interactions. The application is configured to use the 'America/Guatemala' timezone, but despite my efforts, dates are still being handled internally in UTC.

```
SELECT id, "createdAt" FROM sale WHERE id = '5765edc1-1b41-44ce-ac05-a874f16e6960';

+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|                  id                  |        createdAt        |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| 5765edc1-1b41-44ce-ac05-a874f16e6960 | 2023-12-05 20:35:20.127 |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

In the database, the timezone is configured as 'America/Guatemala', but when querying with the program, I get a time that is 6 hours ahead.

```json
{
  "id": "5765edc1-1b41-44ce-ac05-a874f16e6960",
  "subtotal": 5001.25,
  "discount": 5,
  "total": 4996.25,
  "paymentMethod": "CASH",
  "invoiceId": "58517D0F-E9BC-46E6-963A-FE4D6E3F4460",
  "invoiceNumber": "123123fdfd-de",
  "invoiceSerie": "",
  "certificationDate": null,
  "reserveAmount": 0,
  "saleStatus": "BILLED",
  "createdAt": "2023-12-06T02:35:20.127Z",
  "updatedAt": "2023-12-06T02:35:21.666Z"
}
```

I tried formatting the dates after retrieving records from the database using libraries like moment-timezone, but internally, it still uses UTC. This is causing issues with date filtering, and I'm getting incorrect results.

```js
@Injectable()
export class TimezoneInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      map((data) => {
        return this.adjustDates(data);
      }),
    );
  }

  private adjustDates(data: any): any {
    if (data instanceof Array) {
      return data.map((item) => this.adjustDates(item));
    } else if (data instanceof Object) {
      for (const key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && data[key] instanceof Date) {
          data[key] = moment(data[key]).tz('America/Guatemala').format();
        } else if (data[key] instanceof Object || data[key] instanceof Array) {
          data[key] = this.adjustDates(data[key]);
        }
      }
    }

    return data;
  }
```

```js
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: TimezoneInterceptor,
    },
```

Can I do something to make the time when querying from the application the same as in the database?